# getUser return 0 in the second page, only in IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-php-sdk

I working on faccebook app that works fine on all browsers except IE.
When I'm loging into the main page, I'm geting the user id using the (getUser) function, but only in IE, when I'm browsing to the next app pages, the (getUser) function returns zero.

Is there a solution fot this?
Can I use the user id that I got browsing the first page?

Thanks!

Comment: It may have been this issue: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/220904677985962

Answer (score 14):

i have the same problem in my application.

I tried it out and it looked like everything worked great in Safari and Firefox but not IE. It  is a session problem, the session ID was not being passed in IE.

The problem lies with a W3C standard called Platform for Privacy Preferences or P3P for short.  This will allow Internet Explorer to accept your third-party cookie.

You will need to send the header on every page that sets a cookie.

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

This is solution on php.